# CMake project build with multi CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c, cmake

I was using some external stm32-cmake to generate my project which work fine, bu now I try to make my own CMake project with multi CMakeLists.txt files. I don't know how to design my project with CMake so that my root one can see all sub CMake files and did execute command. I know this is a probably duplicate question but I still don't get it how to do this. I try to find some cmake example with multi-cmakes files in directory so that I can guide myself through this build, but I found out that tutorials also change source project files so compiler can find header files like this `#include root/sub-dir/header.h`, which I don't want to change it.

I have problems with designing CMake project with sub-directories. My project directory have now this organization:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cmake
│   ├── toolchain.cmake
│   └── linker_script.cmake
├── Drivers
│   ├── CMSIS
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── Include
│   │   │   ├── arm_common_tables.h
│   │   │   ├── arm_const_structs.h
│   │   │   ├── arm_math.h
│   │   │   ├── core_cm4.h
│   │   └── STM32F4xx
│   │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │       ├── Include
│   │       │   ├── stm32f407xx.h
│   │       │   ├── stm32f4xx.h
│   │       │   └── system_stm32f4xx.h
│   │       └── Source
│   │           └── Templates
│   │               ├── gcc
│   │               │   └── startup_stm32f407xx.s
│   │               └── system_stm32f4xx.c
│   └── HAL
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── Inc
│       │   ├── stm32f4xx_hal_adc.h
│       │   ├── stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.h
│       │   ├── stm32f4xx_hal.h
│       └── Src
│           ├── stm32f4xx_hal_adc.c
│           ├── stm32f4xx_hal.c
│           ├── stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c
├── Inc
│   ├── flatbuffers_common_builder.h
│   ├── flatbuffers_common_reader.h
│   ├── main.h
│   ├── schema_meter_builder.h
│   ├── schema_meter_reader.h
│   ├── schema_meter_verifier.h
│   ├── stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h
│   └── stm32f4xx_it.h
├── lib
│   ├── libflatcc.a 
│   ├── libflatccrt.a 
└── Src
    ├── builder.c
    ├── main.c
    ├── stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c
    ├── stm32f4xx_it.c
    └── system_stm32f4xx.c
```

In my root directory CMakeLists.txt, I have **ADD_EXECUTABLE()** which generate my final .elf file. But this one depends on lot of source files in other sub-directories which I include "sub" CMakeLists.txt with **add_subdirectory()**. I read in CMake book, that large project should have other CMakeLists.txt in sub-directories.

```
#root
SET(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/toolchain.cmake)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

PROJECT(stm32f4discovery)

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.4)
ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM)

add_subdirectory(Drivers/HAL)
add_subdirectory(Drivers/CMSIS)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    Inc
)

SET(PROJECT_SOURCES
    Src/main.c
    Src/stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c
    Src/stm32f4xx_it.c
    Src/builder.c
    Inc/main.h
    Inc/stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf ${PROJECT_SOURCES} ${CMSIS_SOURCES} ${STM32HAL_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf c rdimon m gcc)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf asd)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.elf asdf)
```

I would just like that my sub-directory like Driver/CMSIS CMakeLists.txt just include all (*.h) files so my my root CMakeLists.txt can see it and link onto another sub_directory in /STM32F4xx.

```
#CMSIS
include_directories(Include) 
add_subdirectory(STM32F4xx)
```

In my /STM32F4xx CMakeLists.txt, I try to use **add_library()** so that my files can be "seen" by my root CMakeLists.txt but it doesn't work. Right now it looks like that.

```
#STM32F4XX

SET(CMSIS_DEVICE_HEADERS stm32f4xx.h system_stm32f4xx.h)
SET(CMSIS_DEVICE_SOURCES system_stm32f4xx.c)
SET(CMSIS_STARTUP_SOURCE startup_stm32f407xx.s)


FIND_PATH(CMSIS_DEVICE_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMSIS_DEVICE_HEADERS}
    PATH_SUFFIXES include stm32${STM32_FAMILY_LOWER} cmsis
    HINTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Include/
    CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_BOTH
)

include_directories(CMSIS_INCLUDE_DIRS)

FIND_FILE(CMSIS_${SRC_CLEAN}_FILE ${SRC}
    PATH_SUFFIXES src stm32${STM32_FAMILY_LOWER} cmsis
    HINTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Templates
    CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_BOTH
)
LIST(APPEND CMSIS_SOURCES ${CMSIS_${SRC_CLEAN}_FILE})

FIND_FILE(CMSIS_STARTUP_SOURCE_FILE ${CMSIS_STARTUP_SOURCE}
    PATH_SUFFIXES src stm32${STM32_FAMILY_LOWER} cmsis
    HINTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Templates/gcc/
    CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_BOTH
) 

LIST(APPEND CMSIS_SOURCES ${CMSIS_STARTUP_SOURCE_FILE})

set(PUSH_SOURCE_HEADER_COMBINE
    ${CMSIS_SOURCES}
    ${CMSIS_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

add_library(STATIC ${PUSH_SOURCE_HEADER_COMBINE})
```

But this is clearly wrong to include source files like that.

Comment: you should try to use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html

Comment: your last line `add_library()` the target name is missing (before STATIC)...

Comment: Can you create a github so we can provide you patch ?